# In Grails 3.0 after "create-app MyApp --profile=web-micro" how do you add Spring wiring?

Tags: grails, grails-3.0

In Grails 3.0 with this "web-micro" profile there's no "conf" directory or resources.groovy so I'm looking for the equivalent.

Do you:

- create grails-app/conf/spring/resources.groovy with the usual Groovy BeanBuilder DSL: beans = { ... }
- create a file MyConfig.groovy next to the autogenerated Application.groovy with Java-style spring beans config using @Configuration and @Bean annotations
- same as above setting grails.spring.beans.packages set in application.yml
- something else ...

None of the options above worked for me, but I could have screwed up. What's the "right" way to do this, preferably with the fewest files and lines of code to keep it "micro"?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to use @Bean annotation on methods of your `Application` class. However, creating a `spring/resources.groovy` file in your project directory should work too.

Comment: It seems like this overrides the autoconfigured application context. If I do this I get Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager]: Factory method 'transactionManager' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property 'dataSource' is required